# SparkR on AWS EMR Zeppelin

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin, sparkr

According to the AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/zeppelin-considerations.html

> Zeppelin on Amazon EMR does not support the SparkR interpreter.

Does it mean that it is absolutely impossible to use SparkR with Zeppelin on Amazon EMR or it is possible to install the SparkR for AWS EMR Zeppelin in some custom way after the default EMR cluster is provisioned?

Comment: You can always solve this by installing your own Zeppelin without using the AWS version. You should familiarize yourself with bootstrap actions and create your own installation script to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, I can install the own Zeppelin on my EC2 instance and connect it to my existing AWS EMR and that's it? This way I'll be able to use SparkR via own Zeppelin instance?

Comment: I didn't suggest this solution. But this can also be a solution. You'll need to point out Zeppelin to the cluster